# Minimal investement is not working

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-deployment

```
uint256 public max_contribution = 50 ether; 
    uint256 public min_contribution = 0.1 ether; 
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public payable returns (bool success) {
    require(msg.value >= min_contribution);
    require(msg.value <= max_contribution);
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
    return true;
}
```

using this to set the minimal ETH investement, still receiving tokens when sending 0.1> amount of ETH. Testing on the testnet. Any ideas?
Contract: 0xb1a89c746ecec28bfdf7f06f44b603bf9c035be8 with verified code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion has been created because you posted the code for `transfer` but not the code for the fallback function, just as @mafrasi2 points out.

Now, the fallback function determines the number of tokens and update the balances. Here you can put the restrictions on the amount of ether, like this:

```
function () public payable {
        require(now >= startDate && now <= endDate);
        require(msg.value >= min_contribution);
        require(msg.value <= max_contribution);
        uint tokens;
        if (now <= bonusEnds) {
            tokens = msg.value * 12000;
        } else {
            tokens = msg.value * 10000;
        }
        balances[msg.sender] = safeAdd(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        _totalSupply = safeAdd(_totalSupply, tokens);
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, tokens);
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

But this is not all, you must remove the limits in the transfer function because in the current state the users of your token will never be able to transfer it unless they send ether, which is odd. So transfer should be like this:

```
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
    return true;
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Sir, you`ve just made my week! Thank you very much. Everything is working even if i am sending ehter from MyEtherWallet. Realy appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the ether values that you have on:

```
uint256 public min_contribution = 0.1 ether;
uint256 public max_contribution = XX;
```

**Solidity gets it as Wei by default**, not as ether. **Since a Wei is an indivisible unit, you can't have 0,X Wei.**

Try putting the ether values on Wei knowing that 1 ether = 1E18 Wei.

Maybe this is faster: https://etherconverter.online/

The function seems to be Ok written, so I don't think it's the problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i`ve change it to wei`s, but still receiving tokens when i am sending less then 0.1 ether

Comment: The correction described by @Cpereez19 works, I implemented this in remix and it prevent deposits smaller than 0.1 ether. Be sure that you are compiling and deploying again after the changes.

Comment: Same here, tested the @CPereez19 advice and all works fine on remix.

Comment: But look, ive just did the transaction with 0.01 ether and still the same... https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x10e97daaae2421f5aed498fdfc61bc9289efdfe5de76164d7a6efdc53f07b38c .Maybe its about the way ive tested it? Ive deployed the contract in remix and sent 0.01 from MyEtherWallet to contract address. @Jaime

Comment: Did you just send ether or did you use the transfer function?. In your contract sending ether will just work but sending ether through the transfer function you show in the question will revert if the amount is smaller than 0.1. Let me know.

Comment: @Jaime i`ve just sent ether from MyEtherWallet - just like i would do if i would like to participate in ICO. Everything i need is a minimal transaction rate for the whole contract, like, when i am sending less then 0.1 ether from any wallet i shouldn`t receive tokens.

Comment: Daniel, that wont work with the code you show, sending ether will activate the fallback function. Can you show me all your code?

Comment: @Jaime yes, please, you can see it here, verified and published https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xaaa40e83d6f0f77fd39d313b55cb8e02b90c4640

Comment: @Daniel the solution works, I don't know what are you doing wrong but 3 people tested it and it works..

Comment: That is why i am still here, i can`t understand why that is working for you guys. I just sending less then 0.1 ether from MyEtherWallet - so does the every ICO participant would do and still receiving tokens. My question is how to prevent that @CPereez19

Comment: You have to send the ether using the method transfer() of the contract, if you just send ether to an address, nothing will happen apart of that the ether send goes to the contract (with no requires evaluation)

Comment: But how can other people use my contract then?  @CPereez19

Comment: I just added an answer, it should solve the issue

Comment: If you have a front-end where you give access to it to people, and you obligate the users to send the money using that method transfer(), you will achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

@Jaime hinted at it: you don't call the transfer() function. Instead you are calling this function:

```
function () public payable {
    require(now >= startDate && now <= endDate);
    uint tokens;
    if (now <= bonusEnds) {
        tokens = msg.value * 12000;
    } else {
        tokens = msg.value * 10000;
    }
    balances[msg.sender] = safeAdd(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    _totalSupply = safeAdd(_totalSupply, tokens);
    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, tokens);
    owner.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

Your transfer() function is correct without any modifications. Solidity will convert 0.x ether to wei just fine.

Comment: Everything i need is minimal investement amount for anyone who sending ether to contract address. So for example: Person sending from his ethereum wallet less then 0.1 ether and not receiving any tokens and getting his tranastion back.

Comment: You didn't modify the correct function then. Both `requires(...)` should go into the function I posted, not into `transfer()`. Also, `transfer()` should definitely **not** be `payable`.

Comment: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xaaa40e83d6f0f77fd39d313b55cb8e02b90c4640#code still can receive tokens after less then 0.01 transaction. Also can`t deploy the code when remove payable